# Positioning elements in fixed menu

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have problem with positioning three elements in fixed top menu on my website. I want to look like that: logo on left site, sign in on right site and menu in the middle of navbar.

[image: How my problem looks like in this picture]

How should I do this right?

Comment: Can you show us your source code?

Comment: This problem is solved with @Mamboleoo answer, but thanks anyway :)

Comment: I'm glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create this layout really easily with flexbox !

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/7n1w4sn6/

Apply a `display: flex;` & `justify-content: space-between;` on the container of your menu.

Answer (score 0):

Given that IE does not fully support flex-box, here's an alternative solution which is based on Mamboleoo's code, but uses `float: left;` and `float: right;` on the logo and sign-in link respectively: https://jsfiddle.net/vavx5heb/

Comment: Your demo is the same as mine :/ IE support flexbox since version 10, in most cases people don't have to support IE 8 & 9. The float solution can be bad if you need to vertically align your elements for example.